# Using NOLOCK with EF 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

If you place read operations in a transaction using read-uncommitted (same as NOLOCK), **will other queries be able to get to the data I am getting** since I'm in this transaction?

Comment: what happened when you tested it?

Comment: Even if I tested it, I wouldn't be able to find out if other users could get to the data I was reading. since I'm in a transaction, I'm wondering if that will lock other users out from reading the same data I am reading. I only question it having it inside a transaction. Even though it's read-uncommitted, will other users executing queries for the same data be able to get to it?

Comment: Did you read any documentation about read-uncommitted at all? It's pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, I have, I know what read-uncommitted is. However, If I'm the one using it (inside a transaction), it didn't answer if other queries will be able to get to the same data I'm trying to get to. If I simply ran a stored procedure with NOLOCK, then yes, they would be able to get to the same data. Placing it inside a transaction is the thing I'm unsure about even though it is read-uncommitted. Will placing it inside the transaction lock it up. I don't think so, but want to make sure.

Comment: " wouldn't be able to find out if other users could get to the data I was reading. since I'm in a transaction, " - Incorrect. Even 2 different SSMS active query connections (same user) are sufficient to check this.